# jQuery - only active menu item will change

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, accordion

I'm beginner with jQuery and I would like to change background color to active menu item but and I don't know how. If I select some item background will change but if I select another item, in the previously item stay still "active background color" and I want to change back to default color and only active menu item will be changed.

This is static menu now but I will rebuilt it to dynamic menu from database so I can use some id or anything which will be unique for each menu item.

I have just this because and don't know how next:

```
        $('#accordian h3').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("active1")
        });
```

Complete source is here http://jsfiddle.net/BERRF/. Answer in jsfiddle would be best. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
$("#accordion h3").removeClass("active1");
```

You can see that at the fiddle. Also you don't need 2 click events, you can combine them.

http://jsfiddle.net/sx2Z7/

You just have to remove all active1 classes from every h3 before setting it again, so only your current active will have the white Background Colour.

It's clear or any questions? :)

Answer (score 0):

You start out by 'resetting' the previous chosen element:

```
   $('#accordian h3').click(function () {
       $('.active1').removeClass('active1');
       $(this).addClass("active1")
   });
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one first remove the class `active1` then add

```
 $('#accordian h3').click(function () {
                $('#accordian h3').removeClass("active1")
                $(this).addClass("active1")
            });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BERRF/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your h3.

```
class="accordiontabs"
```

Eg:

```
<h3  class="accordiontabs"><span class="icon-tasks"></span><a href="#">Tasks</a></h3>
```

Add this change your JQuery to

```
$('#accordian h3').click(function () {
                $('.accordiontabs').removeClass("active1");
                $(this).addClass("active1")
            });
```

[LIVE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/shijukbabu/BERRF/6/)